# What is a Markov process?

Tags: probability, markov-process

I am enrolled in some very bad probability/stochastic processes course. Relations hold approximatively, wrong assumptions, no proofs, nothing rigorous and it is a bit frustrating to understand new concepts. It is said that a process $(X_n)$ with respect to the filtration $F_n$ is a Markov process if $$P(X_{n+1} \in B | F_n)=P(X_{n+1} \in B | X_n) \quad \forall B \in \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$$
$$\iff E[g(X_{n+1})| F_n]=E[g(X_{n+1}) | X_n ]  \quad \forall \text{ bounded } g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$$

Alright, no problem. But then exercises are like "Show that $Z_t = Y_1X_1 + Y_2X_2 + ... + Y_{t−1}X_{t−1} + Y_tX_t$ is a Markov process ($X_t, Y_t$ i.i.d.)". **But with respect to which filtration ?** I guess the definition holds if I pick $F_n= \sigma(X_n)$ its natural filtration...

The solution says :  "Rewrite $Z_t = Z_{t−1} + X_tY_t$. The distribution of $Z_t$ only depends on $Z_{t−1}$ since $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are both independent from $t$ and $Z_t$". I really hate this kind of informal maths. The answer has nothing to do with the definition. **Can someone help me understand how to deal with such an exercise ?** How do I identify a Markov process $X_t$ with informal yet legal arguments as they did ? Do I just need to check that $X_t = g(X_{t-1})$ ? The teacher sometimes talks about information at time $t$, but nobody knows how to manipulate this intuition stuff and turn it into valid proofs.

Comment: As a comment, I would striclty take $n$ as an index as you did in the definition, because normally you use $n$ to indicate a process over the natural numbers. $t$ is used for example to indicate a process which has index over the reals.

Comment: The course you enrolled at cannot be that bad to have told you that $F_n=\sigma(X_n)$ is the natural filtration of $Z\,.$ If this was really the case I recommend to search for proper definitions somewhere else. There are plenty of resources in the internet. One of the better ones is https://almostsuremath.com/ by George Lowther.

Comment: Just brute force it formally. After that you can reconcile intuition with the steps of the proof. Here stuff like $E(g(X, Y) \mid X = x) = E(g(x, Y))$ when $X, Y$ are independent will be useful.

Comment: @KurtG. I actually learned that in a much better course where everything was done formally as usual but I am really lost in this informal one

Comment: Then you should improve that question by removing the rants and complaints and formally define the natural filtration of $Z\,.$ You can make your life easier by looking at $Z_n=Z_{n-1}+X_n$ where $X_n$ are i.i.d.

Comment: @KurtG. But the natural filtration was just a side remark, the course's level is very far from knowing it. I feel it just defines a Markov process $X_n$ as a process satisfying $X_t = f (X_{t-1})$

Comment: It does not. The only valuable part of OP above was your correct definition of a Markov process. I will drop out now because your questions are unanswerable. Improve the post as I recommended and I will reconsider it.

Comment: I think calling this definition of Markov processes "correct" is a little generous, though there's definitely a correct definition trapped inside and struggling to get out.  Was this the verbatim definition given in the course, or was it something you put together yourself from another source?  Separately, the "solution" to the exercise is an absolute joke.  Your frustration seems pretty legit to me.  Do you have a textbook for this course?

Comment: @KurtG. I promise I'll edit it once the frustration is gone tomorrow morning, but I would appreciate getting a bit of help here. I always had 100% abstract and extremely rigorous courses and now I feel a bit "betrayed". My question is simply what to do when asked "is $X_n$ a Markov process" ? Since this course is opened for everybody, they tried to make it rigorousless, easier. So is it enough to verify that $X_n = f(X_{n-1})$ in general let's say ?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr this definition was given in the course but it's fine, but when asking us if $X_n$ is a Markov process without specifying the filtration and solving it in this theft way is shameless. It's like wanting to show that an animal X is a cat and proving it ate tuna yesterday... And no textbook unfortunately, no book editor would accept to publish that ofc

Comment: @Kilkik, John Dawkins has worked this out for you. And now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first impulse would be to show that $(Z_n)$ is a Markov process with respect to the filtration $\mathcal F_n:=\sigma\{X_1,Y_1,X_2,Y_2,\ldots,X_n,Y_n\}$. Clearly $Z_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$ measurable for each $n$, by induction.

To check the Markov property you need to show that
$$
E[g(Z_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n]
$$
depends only on $Z_n$. As you noted, $Z_{n+1}=Z_n+X_{n+1}Y_{n+1}$; by hypothesis the pair $(X_{n+1},Y_{n+1})$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n$.  Therefore
$$
E[g(Z_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n]=E[g(Z_{n}+X_{n+1}Y_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n]=h(Z_n),
$$
where $h(z):=E[g(z+X_{n+1}Y_{n+1})]$. (This because of known properties of conditional expectation.) The function $h$ doesn't depend on $n$ becasue the $(X_t,Y_t)$ are iid.

Using the tower property of conditional expectations, you can now show that $(Z_n)$ is a Markov process with respect to its natural filtration $\mathcal G_n:=\sigma\{Z_1,Z_2,\ldots,Z_n\}\subset\mathcal F_n$.

(As a general propostion: If a process is Markov with respect to some filtration $(\mathcal K_n)$ and is adapted to a filtration $(\mathcal H_n)$ with $\mathcal H_n\subset\mathcal K_n$ for all $n$, then it is Markov with respect to $(\mathcal H_n)$. This follows readily from the tower property.)